# Delinking the axes in twin axes charts in Bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to de-link the two y-axes axes in a chart that I have created in Bokeh (like in this example: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#twin-axes) so I can wheel-zoom on each y-axis or move each axis separately. I have been looking around for hours but haven't been able to found an answer yet.

Comment: The question does not have enough information. If this is standalone content, then only `CustomJS` callbacks are possible. It this is a Bokeh server application, then there are other possibilities. Please describe your use case in more detail.